# How do I say I saw you

Tags: translation

In a non creepy way maybe?

(additional question, how would I respond to that claim with 'it turned out to be someone else')

Comment: Hello, and welcome to JL&U. It is usually considered a good idea to include your own best guess at how a sentence might be phrased within your question text, so that we can see how much you've been able to figure out via your own research - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center for more information. If you could please [edit your question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/52535/edit) to include this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking for translations are off-topic in this site unless prior research effort is clearly indicated. We're here to help you learn, not to provide a bulk translation service.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the feeling you're trying to convey would best be expressed with "見かける".  "見る" is literally "to see".  "見かける" is more like "to happen to see" or "to catch sight of".  Of course saying "あなたを見ました" makes sense, but to a native speaker it sounds so literal--sort of like saying "I saw the signpost."  I think you should say "X-さんを見かけました".  If this person is an acquaintance or friend, you should use the more informal past tense form of "見かける" and say "X-さんを見かけた".

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ura's great answer:

If you want to say you thought you saw someone but it turned out to someone else you could say something like

> Xーさんを見かけたと思ったが間違いでした
>
> I thought I saw so-and-so but I was mistaken (lit. it was a mistake).

Then you could say

> 実はXーさんでした
>
> It was actually so-and-so